# nexe, node and sqlite3

Tags: node.js, node-sqlite3

I'm trying to get nexe working with a node program that uses sqlite3.   When I try I get this at runtime:

```
package.json must declare these properties:
binary.module_name
binary.module_path
binary.host
```

and I've read everything I can on the web - I've found plenty of articles that say node-pre-gyp is not supported, some that say you've gotta create some mysterious .node file, in fact many use sqlite3 as an example - but nothing that gives me the slightest clue as to how to actually get it working.

I tried installing sqlite with --build-from-source, which was an ordeal all by itself, but that did nothing.  Can anyone explain *exactly* how to get nexe working with sqlite3.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't really get an answer to this question - but for anyone interested - pkg just worked for me - so I went and used that instead.

As for the .node files - that appears to be an output from node-pre-gyp - and just lives in your node_modules directory - so you can ferret around in there and find it.

but anyway - my fix to this was to use pkg.